# Java run c program with options

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I have this code:

```
try {
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
            "/Applications/TorBrowser_en-US.app/Contents/MacOS/./tor",
            "-f /Applications/TorBrowser_en-US.app/Library/filetctor/torrc")
            .start();
    p.waitFor();
    int exitVal = p.exitValue();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Every time i execute it, i get a 255 exitValue. The process doesn't run properly.

If i run the program with only:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/Applications/TorBrowser_en-US.app/Contents/MacOS/./tor").start();
```

The process runs correctly. But i need to use the -f option.

What is the problem? Am i writing it incorrectly?

Comment: The `-f` and the file path should almost certainly be separate parameters.

Comment: Did you try to run the application on its own? What error does it return? Try and fetch it with `getInputStream()` or `getErrorStream()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each argument should be a separate string, not all in a single space-separated string.

See [the example in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

> `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");`

Comment: Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/Applications/TorBrowser_en-US.app/Contents/MacOS/./tor", "-f", "/Applications/TorBrowser_en-US.app/Library/filetctor/torrc").start(); WORKS